# Software to capture high quality screen-casts

Tags: after-effects, screen-casting, tutorial

I want to record video tutorials but I can't get the program to capture my screen with high quality, and not just that, when I try to edit it in After Effects scaling and positioning the fonts and window seem pixelized and doesn't look sharp. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of screen recording software, for example:

1. [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) (free)
2. [Screenpresso](http://vegasaur.com/Screenpresso) (free/paid versions)
3. [Movavi Screen Capture Studio](http://screencapture.movavi.org/) ($49.95)
4. [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) ($299.00)

Answer (score 5):

What are you using currently?

I use [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) and it works pretty well, I can record portions of the screen or the entire screen with the native screen resolution [1280x800].

Comment: +1 Using Camtasia Studio here too. Sharp and clear.

Comment: @tecfreak I use total recorder, is there any free soft?

Answer (score 4):

I use [ActivePresenter](http://atomisystems.com). The best free screen recorder I've known. It contains everything you need to make a professional screencast.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution, I'd recommend `recordmydesktop`. You can install it in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install recordmydesktop
```

Afterwards, run it from a terminal, using the desired filename as an argument:

```
recordmydesktop tutorial23.ogv
```

Stop recording by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Mac, give [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm) a try. It offers lossless screen recording which can be exported for use in Premiere or other NLE's and it's inbuilt editing is pretty good too for quick edits.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compatible Nividia GPU then Nvidia Shadowplay is a great screen recorder, it can do 4K at 60fps with a 50MBPS bitrate, has low CPU usuage and is free. It can also capture the last 5-20 minutes of what was on your screen. The file sizes can get a bit big but you can reduce the quality to what you want and can delete the video files after making the video that used the footage. All other software others have mentioned are also very good.

http://www.geforce.co.uk/geforce-experience/shadowplay

Happy recording and have a nice day!